# Back button with Cordova/phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, events, button

I am creating an application using the framework cordova. I need to intercept the "Back" button of the phone itself in order to perform the various aoperazioni, for example closing a modal dialog. The problem is that now, once you open the modal, I can not close it by pressing the back button. What happens is that you close any application. How could I do to intercept this event which is not part of the app but the phone? I refer to the actual button of a smartphone. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with Javascript using Phonegap's Event API

```
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
            // your code
    } , false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the docs?

Here's what you need: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton